# The name of a robotics tool that is only a sharpened rod

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, technical

There is a tool used in robotics that is essentially just a rod of metal with a sharp point.

[image]

It is fastened to the robot not for the purpose of manipulating, stabbing or poking holes, but solely so the user can move the robot to a certain point in space. The tip of the tool provides a sharp reference point, and the user can move the robot until that point is at the desired position.

The German word I heard most often is "*Teachspitze*" or "*Teachdorn*", which is a faux-English term meaning "teaching tip" or "teaching thorn".

What is this tool called? Is there a professional term for it?

Comment: Try "idiot stick".

Comment: Since this is a technical term in a narrow area, you'd probably have better luck at a robotics site.

Comment: @JohnLawler For real? "idiot stick" on [google](http://www.google.com/search?q="idiot+stick") gives no results that seem to have any relation to the tool I am looking for, even when used in conjunction with [robotics](https://www.google.com/search?q="idiot+stick"+robotics).

Comment: It's a nonce form that's usually slang for a shovel or hoe -- a stick with a tool on one end and an idiot on the other. In this case, the idiot would be the robot.

Comment: So _that_'s what those things the Daleks had were.

Answer (score 2):

For a milling machine it is called an **edge finder** or **edge indicator**.
You use it to locate (in the milling machines axis) a point on the work piece.

On a [coordinate measuring machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate-measuring_machine#Mechanical_probe) they are known as a **probe tip** or **probe indicator**

Often they have an electrical detector which senses touching another metal part, or are very delicately sprung so they flip out of the way at the slightest touch of the part.